# DirectShow's SampleGrabber retrieves erroneous sample

Tags: c++, c, windows, directshow

Being a newbie to DS I needed a SampleGrabber that can handle VIDEOINFOHEADER2, which IMediaDet cannot.

So I took the SampleGrabber from DX8.1 samples which - in contrast to the stock grabber - allows all kind of media.
I used the sample code quite as is, and grabbing one single frame everything seems to work fine: the graph is built without returning errorcodes etc.
Then calling

```
    hr = pSeeking->SetPositions( 
        &Seek, 
        AM_SEEKING_AbsolutePositioning, 
        NULL, 
        AM_SEEKING_NoPositioning );
```

with Seek = 2

the callback is called:

HRESULT Callback( IMediaSample * pSample, REFERENCE_TIME * StartTime, REFERENCE_TIME * StopTime, BOOL TypeChanged )

The problem is with the buffer:
It has the right size (GetSize () == 691200 = 3 Byte * 640 * 320)
but its content is all "205", which cannot be (in which format ever).

Suspicious about it:
The parameters of "Callback" are StartTime = 834168, StopTime = 1251251 and TypeChanged = 1.

I tried showing the Graph at GraphEdit
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
but wasn't successful ("application is busy" from GraphEdit).

Where might the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it (at last).

In the callback I copied the delivered buffer, with memcpy, and confused source and destination. Very embarrassing.

Thanks for the help. (Will try to delete this question in a few days after everybody has read, as it's of very limited use).

Comment: I know nothing about DirectShow, apart from some dabbling in it like 20+ years ago. The only thing I saw was the 0xCD clue. Yes, I agree, delete the question as it turns out it has nothing to do with DirectShow.

Comment: I will. But - to point out once more - your hint was a help indeed. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, memory is set to various patterns to help debug invalid memory references. 205 is 0xCD in hex, and this means [uninitialized heap memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). So you are not getting "erroneous" data, the data is never getting written.

You may not be able to seek. Did you try calling [`IsFormatSupported`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407035(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yes, somewhere around there must be the problem.

GetTimeFormat returns TIME_FORMAT_MEDIA_TIME.
IsFormatSupported on that returns false.
So I tried SetTimeFormat (TIME_FORMAT_FRAME) - which returns S_OK,
but IsFormatSupported still reports false.
Tried SetTimeFormat (TIME_FORMAT_SAMPLE) then, which returns E_FAIL.
IsFormatSupported now reports still false, but - sit down now -
if I do a GetTimeFormat before (says still TIME_FORMAT_FRAME)
then IsFormatSupported reports true afterwards.
Boing!
CheckCapabilities after this (does it depend on the set TimeFormat?)
says ... (continued)

Comment: (continued) ... says AM_SEEKING_CanSeekAbsolute.

I do this before performing the seek (pSeeking->SetPositions).
I suspect that just this is running the graph?

Well, totally confused ...

Comment: In one more try to visualize the constructed filter graph with GraphEdit I included the AddRot-code from MSDN again and to prevent the "server is busy" message while debugging my application I included a endless loop around a ::Sleep(100) after building the graph, before the Seek-command. GraphEdit responds then and shows ... nothing ... a blank (reddish) sheet. What does this all mean? Hasn't the filter graph been built at all? But at Windows's desktop the icon from the LAV-codec shows up. Please help, I'm stuck.

Comment: Succeeded in dumping the graph (after building, before seeking) to the debug output by "DumpGraph( pGraph, 0 )".
Everything looks fine:
source - AVI-Splitter - LAV Video Decoder - grabber - (null) renderer.
(The video is of simple kind that even can be used with IMediaDet.)
So ...
Why hasn't the callback has buffer content?
Why the strange behaviour (see above) concerning Seekability?